# Set selected TreeItem in TreeView

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have a TreeView that is inside a GridPane. A certain function requires the user to select a TreeItem and click on button on the screen. After the function associated with the button is completed, I want the focus to go back to the TreeItem that was previously selected in the TreeView.

At the end of the button action, I have:

`TreeItem<String> selectedItem = [TreeItem that was last selected]`

How can I give focus back to the TreeView with `selectedItem` highlighted?

Neither the TreeView or TreeItem have a `setSelected` method I can use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To select an item:

```
TreeView treeView = ... ; // initialize this
TreeItem treeItem = ... ; // initialize this, too
MultipleSelectionModel msm = treeView.getSelectionModel();

// This line is the not-so-clearly documented magic.
int row = treeView.getRow( treeItem );

// Now the row can be selected.
msm.select( row );
```

That is, get the **row** of the `treeItem` from its `treeView`, then pass that **row** into the `treeView`'s selection model.

Aside, the `TreeView` API could be improved to delegate for a single tree item:

```
treeView.select( treeItem );
```

Unfortunately, no such method exists.

Comment: Note: This mechanism will not auto-expand the tree in which the to-be-selected item resides. Instead, `getRow()` will just return -1 in that case. Depending on the use case, it may be necessary to call `TreeItem.setExpended(true)` on the whole parent chain.

Answer (score 6):

[TreeView.getSelectionModel()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#getSelectionModel()) offers:

- [getSelectedItem](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#getSelectedItem())
- [setSelectedItem](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#setSelectedItem(T))

These are protected methods, so consider using [select](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#select(int)).

Comment: I was aware of this method but I have no idea how to use `getSelectedItem` and `setSelectedItem` using this method.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? At first you store the currently selected item, then perform some actions, afterwards you can restore the selection to the previously stored value..?

Comment: No, what I meant was I don't know how to use this method. Eg: `theTreeView.setSelectionModel(what-parameter-goes-here?);` and how do I call `setSelectedItem`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myTreeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectedItem(...)` As @eckig says, the selection model has the `getSelectedItem()` and `setSelectedItem(...)` methods.

Comment: @john by default the TreeView already has a default SelectionModel. Unless you want to change the default-behaviour you dont have to provide your own and can use the default by calling myTreeView.getSelectionModel()...

Comment: I understand I need to use `setSelectedItem` and for that I need to use `setSelectionModel()` and not `getSelectionModel()`. Am I right? Because `getSelectionModel()` does not have a `setSelectedItem` under it.

Comment: Okay, we are talking java right? getSelectionModel() returns an Object of type MultipleSelectionModel offering the listed methods...

Comment: For an obscure reason, the API has changed and now it's "select(T obj)".

Comment: @pdem Both methods do exist as of JavaFX 8.

Comment: @eckig setSelectedItem is protected and from the code should not be used since 'select' method wrap it and do more things :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#setSelectedItem-T- whatever, 'select' method do want we want.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand (...) on the comment made by malamut to the chosen answer, and also to clarify something:

Actually, you do not have to do two operations (find row, then select row). This works fine:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().select( treeItem );
```

But, with this, or any other method to set selection programmatically, this will simply fail if the tree item is not *showing*. "Showing" is not the same as *visible*: a node can be showing but not be visible, for example with a `ScrollPane`, where the part of the tree in question has been scrolled out of view.

"Showing" means that all ancestors of the `TreeItem` in question, up to and including the root `TreeItem`, are expanded. There appears to be no built-in method to accomplish this currently (JavaFX 11). So you'd typically do something like this before attempting programmatic selection:

```
for( TreeItem ti = treeItemToBeSelected; ti.getParent() != null; ti = ti.getParent() ){
    ti.getParent().setExpanded( true );
}
```