# JavaFX TreeView remember last selected item after refresh

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, treeview, refresh

I develop a JavaFX GUI application and I have a problem with a node called "TreeView". My tree should represent a file structure inside a specific directory. The user is supposed to conduct some typical operations on those files like copying, removing or renaming them.

After that happens, I'd like the tree to be refreshed (it means that it is supposed to load once again the structure from the file system). The issue is that, once it is done, the selection on one of the tree items is lost and every directory is collapsed. I would like the selection to be persistent, and all the parent directories to be expanded, even after the content of the tree has been refreshed.

I've tried numerous solutions so far to address this issue, but none of them let me select **the same tree item (apart from the deleting operation of course) and expand all needed roots** as before. My question is, how can this be achieved? I guess the main problem here is the fact, that I load all the data once again and therefore my new tree items do not match with the "old" ones.

I would appreciate all hints that you can give me in that matter.

I tried to save the item with getSelectionModel() and then set it, it doesn't select the same item as before (it ignores that directories are not expanded).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929276/set-selected-treeitem-in-treeview Duplicate..

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I can't make it select the same item with expanding all the parents...even if I store the selected treeitem and try to choose it after the tree has been reloaded it doesn't select the right item