# First child of TreeItem in TreeView has wrong index

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-8

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929276/set-selected-treeitem-in-treeview) thread, I am attempting to do the following... (simplified for discussion sake).

```
TreeItem<Step> item = new TreeItem<>(step);
parent.getChildren().add(0, item);
int row = treeView.getRow(item);  //row here is -1?
```

The reason for this is I am trying to select the added item in it's absolute position in the tree using...

```
TreeTableViewSelectionModel<Step> msm = treeView.getSelectionModel();
msm.select(row);
```

So, the first child doesn't get selected.  But, this works for all added Tree items except the very first child item of any parent.  Following TreeItems have the correct row number and are properly selected.  Not understanding why the position isn't correct. The other odd thing is I tried the following..

```
if (row == -1)
{
   TreeItem<Step> parent = newStep.getParent(); //First parent at 0
   row = treeView.getRow(parent) + 1;           //Now row = 1
}

msm.select(row);
```

The parent TreeItem is STILL selected instead of the child.  Again, all this works after adding the first child. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: After further testing, it seems as the the item is technically selected.  That is to say the application behaves as if the correct item is selected, but the parent TreeItem still graphically appears to be selected in the TreeView (i.e. it is highlighted).  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I see you added an item into some parent: parent.getChildren().add(0, item); but call getRow() from a treeView. Are parent and treeView the same?

Comment: Is the new item's parent expanded? Why not just select the item directly with `msm.select(item)`?

Comment: @James_D - Thanks for your response.  I did switch to use msm.select(item).  The result wasn't any different.

Comment: @DmytroMaslenko - The parent in the most simple case is the root TreeItem in the TreeView.  But, the problem happens for any first child of a parent TreeItem.